# How to extract the List of software versions that are successor versions and they also have successor versions, from a table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables from oracle datasets as follow:

[image]

[image]

- List item

I would like to have the list of software versions that are successor versions and they also have successor versions

Expected results:

[image]

- List item

and then I would like to have the list of software that at least 1x were processed (but not by Mr. Müller)

Expected results:

[image]

My code that I have written so far for the first part:

```
SELECT name
FROM software
WHERE previous_version is not Null 
AND ?????
group by Name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

list of software :

```
select * from software where previous_version is not null and softnr in (Select previous_version from software where previous_version is not null)
```

For the second part. It's impossible to answer. You didn't show how the two tables are linked.

For next questions, please rephrase them correcly : There is nothing called "List of software versions that are successor versions and they also have successor versions, from a table"

You can use : How to write an SQL Query ? How to link two tables ? etc... You have to use a generic title. Only you understands : List of software versions that are successor versions and they also have successor versions